# Opening android studio from any directory in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio

How i can open android studio in Ubuntu from any directory adding PATH variable? 
I unzipped android studio on my Desktop then i tried following commands in terminal.

PATH=$PATH:/Desktop/android-studio/bin/

After that i run studio.sh.

./studio.sh

But it is not working. I can not open from any directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to execute without `./`

The `./` indicates the current folder. Without it you can execute from anywhere in your system

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently and I want to share my solution that can be useful for future readers. I think your path variable is not set correctly. I did the same but it did not work, solution that worked following:

Edit `~/.profile:`

```
gedit ~/.profile
```

Go to the following line:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

change it to :

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:/home/your_user_name/Desktop/android-studio/bin/"
```

you can see from screenshot where I have defined my `/opt/android-studio/bin`, instead of it, you should do the same:

[image]